# Calendar is not displaying correctly using flatpickr

Tags: node.js, reactjs, flatpickr

I installed flatpickr by npm install flatpickr. Calender is displaying like when click on input control [image]

```
var React = require('React');
var ReactDOM = require('ReactDOM');
var Flatpickr = require('flatpickr');

var Calender = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function(){
    this.flatpickr = new Flatpickr(this.refs.date, {dateFormat: "m/d/Y"});
    },

    render: function() {
        return(
                <div>            
                    <input data-enable-time defaultValue='2016-11-11' ref="date_from" />    
                </div>
             );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I know its been a long time but-
You need to add the link to the CSS file.

In your SCSS file:

```
@import '../node_modules/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css';
```

It's the first line in the the docs example:
https://github.com/coderhaoxin/react-flatpickr
(When I used it I found that the css file name in the example was different than what I had, so double check that in your node_modules.)

Hope that helped.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and the answer seems not working for me, as it's  2 years old, is there another fix?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working on a system developed by someone else. I totally forgot to add the css in a new template and spend around 3 hours :(

Comment: In my case it was solved with `@import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css';`

Comment: If you are using vuexy then this will work 
`import "@styles/react/libs/flatpickr/flatpickr.scss";`